# Predict function in R not giving an interval

Tags: r, predict

I'm trying to use `predict()` in R to compute a prediction interval for a linear model. When I tried this on a simpler model with only one covariate, it gave the expected output of a point estimate with a confidence interval. When I added a categorical predictor to the model, the `predict()` output gives what seems like a single-point estimate with no interval. I've Googled to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here?

```
medcost <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:100),
  charges = sample(0:100000, 100, replace = T),
  bmi = sample(18:40, 100, replace = T),
  smoker = factor(sample(c("smoker", "nonsmoker"), 100, replace = TRUE))
)

mod2 <- glm(charges ~ bmi + smoker, data = medcost)

predict(mod2, interval="predict",
        newdata = data.frame(bmi=c(29, 31.5), smoker=c("smoker", "smoker")))
```

Comment: You'll get an interval if you use `lm()` instead of `glm()`.  As the link @Quinten posted says, `glm()` doesn't do them, because they don't make sense in some GLMs.  But when you don't say the family, `glm()` defaults to `"gaussian"`, and that's the same model as `lm()` uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the standard error, you could use `se.fit = TRUE` like this:

```r
mod2 <- glm(charges ~ bmi + smoker, data = medcost)
predict(mod2, interval="predict",
        newdata = data.frame(bmi=c(29, 31.5), smoker=c("smoker", "smoker")),
        se.fit = TRUE)
#> $fit
#>        1        2 
#> 47638.66 47106.14 
#> 
#> $se.fit
#>        1        2 
#> 4304.220 4475.473 
#> 
#> $residual.scale
#> [1] 28850.85
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

I would recommend you having a look at this post: [R: glm(...,family=poisson) plot confidence and prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154944/r-glm-family-poisson-plot-confidence-and-prediction-intervals)

Comment: Interesting. That's helpful, thanks. Can you explain why predict() readily gave me an interval with upper and lower bounds when I was using just one continuous predictor, but it can't now? The post you link discusses Poisson and logistic models, but this is just a linear model.